# Reading a resistance to earth sensor with a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, voltage-divider, automotive, teensy

What are the options for reading a resistance to earth sensor from a microcontroller?

Scenario:  I'm building a digital dash for a vintage car, using a Teensy 4 as the microcontroller.  The car is a typical 12V body earth type setup where the oil, fuel and temperature sensors are single wire, variable resistance to earth.  The dash is intended to be a drop in replacement and I can't change the sensors.

I'm thinking I could use the sensor as the second part of a voltage divider with R3 to prevent overloading the teensy in case the sensor is disconnected.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYZdQQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Notes:

- The car is 12V system, but like all such cars the voltage can vary from 11.5 up to about 14.5V
- I do have a 6.6v, 5v (and 3.3v if necessary) supplies available via buck converters from the 12V.  Presumably these will be more stable than the 12V system.
- I don't need a high resolution.  The teensy can provide 10-bit resolution, but half or even quarter of that would suffice.
- I'm after the simplest circuit that will work well.  Any filtering, calibration etc... can be done in software.

Questions:

1. Will this setup work or is there a different approach I should consider?
2. Assuming the above circuit is the basic idea, are there any pros/cons to using 12v vs 6.6v vs 5v as the supply voltage?  eg: will 5v be too adversely affected by the long run of cable to the fuel sensor in the back of the car (say 3m)
3. What else should I consider to further protect the teensy?

(fwiw: I'm a software engineer with good understanding of software and digital electronics but pretty much a novice when it comes to analog electronics - so any advice much appreciated).

Comment: Just for nomenclature, earth means physically connected to the earth (like the earth of an electrical outlet. Here you should use the term ground or reference.

Comment: @Julien That makes sense, fair point. I've probably been influenced by the docs that came with the car's wiring kit - they use the term "earth".  Maybe an Australian thing?

Comment: It might be a terminology used in the car industry. I'm not in that field!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protecting with a resistor is a bad idea because it will affect your measurement. Use a zener diode or a TVS diode instead.

Yes, you should use a regulated power supply to operate. I would select 3.3V, but due to the length of wire, 5V might be better suited.

Even if you mentioned accuracy isn't an issue, an unregulated power supply will be very hard to compensate for in software. So, I would definitely go with a regulated rail. Of course, having meters of wire will be lossy but, you can compensate for that.

In your application, a voltage divider should be sufficient to measure the sensor. If it's not, it gets a bit more complicated, so lets hope it's fine.

Regarding the protection for the Teensy, a resistor is useless. I would advise you to place a series resistor with a zener diode before entering the MCU. Adding a low pass filter wouldn't be a bad idea either since it is simple and will reject a lot of noise in your application. Something like this should be fine.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi07bd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you may, or may not know, a Zener diode, just like any diode allow forward current but also allow reverse current to go through but at a much higher voltage and will clip it at that point. So let say you use a 4V zener diode, if the voltage gets higher then 4V, the diode will let the current pass until the voltage is back bellow 4V (not how it happens but that is the principle in simple terms). So you can use this diode to protect for over voltage. The resistor in line serve 2 purpose. The first is to limit the current going through the zener diode and the second is to create a low pass filter with the capacitor.

How to find all the right components:

1. Select your power rail
2. Select the pull up resistor. If their are no restriction, it should be the same value as the nominal value of your sensor­.
3. Select your diode based on the voltage that can enter your ADC. Select it between the absolute maximum and the operation voltage desired.
4. The diode you selected has a reverse current rating. Evaluate what is the maximum voltage you could see at your sensor due to any malfunction of the car. In your case, I'd say around 15V. The formula to calculate the resistor is simple. Calculate the maximum voltage drop on the resistor: Vmax-Vdiode=Vdrop then using the maximum reverse current of the diode Vdrop/Ireversemax=R
5. Now you have the resistor decided, select your capacitor in function of the cutoff frequency. Nyquist would say half your sampling rate, but in DC signal, I wouldn't worry too much. Use a LP filter calculator to figure the capacitor value.

You should have all the component figured out!

Comment: thanks for that.  1) In your diagram where you say "From Sensor" do you mean from the output of a voltage divider? 2) Is D1 in your diagram the zenor diode you refer to in your first paragraph?

Comment: @BradRobinson I modified my answer to explicit more the schematic and help you in the component selection. If you have any followup question, let me know!

Comment: Hi @Julien,  that's awesome.  It'll take me a bit to process all that but I'll dig through it tonight and let you know if I have any questions.  Big help, thanks.